# Magento: How to import orders from another DataBase

Tags: magento, orders

I am searching the best method to import old orders from Database (the old website) to magento Database

knowing that:

-Magento-site is functional.

-Many Product exist in the old database but doesn't exist in new magento database.

Please, can you help me know the best method to import these commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can go with following steps:

1. Export all the products from your db which is needed
2. Import products to new db ( so that now your old and new db equal)
3. Export all customer_ and sales_ tables from your source database ( these tables contains all your Orders, Invoices, Credit memos data)
4. Before importing step - 3 tables to your new db first you need to disable foreign key constraint checkup
   **To Disable :** SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
5. Import all your tables to new db
6. Update eav_entity_store table for column inserted_last_id ( This step is required to tell magento to picks order id after which was last order id)
7. Enable foreign key constrint checkup
   **To Enable :** SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

For more details you can [check here.](http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2013/11/move-magento-sales-customers/)

Comment: Thank you so much! for this one: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard task but it can be done.

First of all you should import the products to the Magento site, even if the products are not active but just to get a live reference by sku. The second thing I think is to migrate the users from the old site to the Magento site. All of them should know that their passwords will change eventually.

Then I think you should create the orders programmatically and take into consideration the cicle of an order in Magento: Order -> Invoice -> Shipping therefore and finally you should automatically complete each order. Maybe this link will be usefull:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/

Regards!

Comment: Thanks very much Ricardo,                                            
- I have migrating the users from the old site.
- I have importing many product.
- I 'm going to finished the code who can create automatically the order.

Now, I have one problem concerning  some products who doesn't exist on new site.